# Fill an array with dates when $http/rest requests did not return a response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I want to perform an http/rest request for 30 days and fill an array with the dates that did not return a response. What is a good way to do this? I don't know a good pattern for it and find it confusing because of the asynchronous nature of http/rest requests.

The code below works but it stores recent reported. I want to store recent unreported.

```
        $scope.recentReported = [];

        $scope.getRecentReported = function () {
          var dateToday = new Date();
          for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
            var dateThen = moment(dateToday).add(-i, 'days');
            RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen)
              .then(
                function (response) {
                  if (response) {
                    $scope.recentReported.push(response.date);
                  }
                }
              );
          }
        };
```

Comment: Why does your `RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue` not resolve a promise for unreported?  That seems like a bad idea.  Instead have it reject the promise or return an error code.

Comment: I agree that it's not ideal, but I can't do anything about the back-end right now.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you need to use $q and chain your $http calls.
First get an array with the dates:

```
  var dates = [];
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
    dates.push(moment(dateToday).add(-i, 'days'));
  }
```

Then chain your calls like so:

```
$q.all(dates.map(function(dateThen){
  return RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen);  
})).then(function(results){
  //results now contains some null values for the responses that did not return any value
  results.forEach(function(result, resultIndex){
    if(!result){
      $scope.recentUnReported.push(//your fill up here);
    };
  });
});
```